# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, composer

So I'm trying to get [calcinai/xero-php](https://packagist.org/packages/calcinai/xero-php) installed using Composer but am getting this error in specific.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package calcinai/xero-php No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by calcinai/xero-php[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I've tried installing both by adding `"calcinai/xero-php": "1.5.*"` to my require list and by entering `composer require calcinai/xero-php` in the terminal.

Here is the json file currently:

```
{
    "name": "calcinai/xero-php",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "A client implementation of the Xero API, with a cleaner OAuth interface and ORM-like abstraction.",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php",
    "license": "MIT",

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "calcinai/xero-php": "1.5.*"
    },

    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.7",
        "fabpot/goutte": "~2.0",
        "twig/twig": "1.16.2"
    },

    "repositories": [
    ],

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "XeroPHP\\": "src/XeroPHP/"
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by adding  `"version": "1.5.0",` after `"description"` in composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

require: php: >=5.5.0, ext-curl, ext-openssl, calcinai/xero-php: ^1.8

Here is the json file currently:

```
{
    "name": "calcinai/xero-php",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "A client implementation of the Xero API, with a cleaner OAuth interface and ORM-like abstraction.",
    "version": "1.8.6",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php",
    "license": "MIT",

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "calcinai/xero-php": "^1.8"
    },

    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.7",
        "fabpot/goutte": "~2.0",
        "twig/twig": "1.16.2"
    },

    "repositories": [
    ],

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "XeroPHP\\": "src/XeroPHP/"
        }
    }
}
```